# how to connect angular app on public ip and a node app on local ip?

Tags: node.js, angular, ip, localhost

I have an angular 4 app which is running on 151.233.x.y:8080 and I have a node app which is running on 192.168.t.z:3000! I want to make a connection between them with an HTTP service. the base URL in my service is http://192.168.t.z and my angular app is running by `ng serve --port 8080 --host 192.168.87.19 --public 151.233.58.231` but I cannot connect to my node app successfully! whats the problem?

Comment: Local IP addresses are not accessible outside your home network. You can not access local ip addresses from public network.

Comment: @MukeshKumar is there any way to solve it? I just want to run my app on the local server that can be accessible from outside

Comment: Public cannot be connected to local. Local can be connected to public with right permissions of open port requests/responses. Please get both on public

Answer (score 0):

const _isDev = window.location.port.indexOf('8080') > -1;

const protocol = window.location.protocol;

const host = window.location.host;

const apiURI = _isDev ? 'http://192.168.t.z:3001/' : '';

export const CNF = {
    appName : 'Demo',
    BASE_URI: protocol + "//" + host + '/',
    BASE_API: apiURI,
};

Use CNF.BASE_API when you use get post method in http requset.
Its working only your system.Outside is not working.

Comment: i did this but192.168.t.z is local and its not accessible from public ip! ;((